# How to remove web test alert

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Some weeks ago I created an alert for one of my Azure services. Now I keep getting e-mail alerts and can't find where to turn them off. Nothing in the alert e-mails give me a clue where to find the settings for the alert, except for the reference to the management portal, but I don't find anything about alerts in there.

Since I'm quite new to Azure I've just been playing around to see what's in there. I do not remember for which of my test projects I activated the alerts, and I have created and deleted some Azure web sites and web roles while testing. "webresults.web" is the name of the MVC web project in the most current Azure solution, and also the name of the web role in the same solution.

The e-mails look like this:

> Dear Customer,
>     'WebTest: team 1-webresults.web crossed the configured threshold of failed locations' was activated for webresults.web
>
> You can view more details for this alert in the Microsoft Azure Management Portal.
>
> SERVICE: webresults.web
>
> WEB TEST NAME: team 1-webresults.web crossed the configured threshold of failed locations for the last 15 minutes
>
> THRESHOLD OF NUMBER OF FAILED LOCATIONS: 3
>
> ALERT ACTIVATED TIME (UTC): 11/04/2014 23:02:00
>
> SUBSCRIPTION NAME: Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Professional

To be clear: How do I remove the alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an issue we are fixing soon where when the application insights resource is deleted (but not the resource group) the tagged webtests will remain (including the alert rule and email notifications).  You have 2 options to remove the webtest.
1. Delete the resource group where the webresults.web application insights resource existed in (likely the same resource group where your website existed or a resource group called "Default-ApplicationInsights-CentralUS" if the application insights resource was created from Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 .  To see the list of resource groups in your subscription, choose Browse -> Resource Groups.
2. Send me the azure subscription id (ie. the guid) and I can delete all the webtests from the subscription.  vladj @ Microsoft . com

Comment: I went with option 2. Vlad has helped med remove the tests (and corresponding alerts).

I hope that this issue will be fixed soon, so that you guys at Microsoft won't have to help all users manually like you helped me.

Comment: this seems to still be an issue. i have a webtest that cannot be delete or removed.